# Encrypt/Decrypt a MS Access 2000 (*.mdb) Database File (Extra Security)

Tags: delphi, ms-access, encryption, delphi-7

For Extra Security, i would like to Encrypt/Decrypt a MS Access 2000 (*.mdb)  Database File.

I am using Delphi 7 and I am looking for a free or opensource solution (possible just two functions that allow you to pass a file name and a key).

I would like to perform the decrypt before my app starts, and the encrypt when the app shuts down.  Where are the best places to do this. OnCreate, OnDestroy events?

I assume i would first have to create a small utility which uses the encrypt portion of the solution to encrypt the database file first?

thanks

Comment: What exactly do you think you'll be accomplishing by doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the reasons which you have to encrypt your old access database , because the security of access 2000 and 2003 is very weak. but my primary recommendation is which try to upgrade to Access 2007 or higher which uses the Microsoft Cryptographic API,  and incorporates significant improvements in security.

If you can't upgrade, here i leave an option to encrypt your mdb file.

1) to encrypt you data  you can use the `JwaWinCrypt` unit which is part of the  Jedi `JWSCL` library, you can download this library from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jedi-apilib/files/JEDI%20API%202.3%20and%20JEDI%20WSCL%200.9.3.zip/download).

check this sample function which uses [3DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) algorithm to encrypt a file.

```
uses
  Classes,
  JwaWinType,
  JwaWinCrypt,
  SysUtils;


procedure CryptFile(Const InFileName, OutFileName, Password: AnsiString; Encrypt: Boolean);
const
  BufferSize=1024*64;
var
  StreamSource  : TFileStream;
  StreamDest    : TFileStream;
  CRYPTPROV     : HCRYPTPROV;
  CRYPTHASH     : HCRYPTHASH;
  CRYPTKEY      : HCRYPTKEY;
  Buffer        : LPBYTE;
  BytesIn       : DWORD;
  Final         : Boolean;
begin
  CryptAcquireContext(CRYPTPROV, nil, nil, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT);
  try
      CryptCreateHash(CRYPTPROV, CALG_3DES_112, 0, 0, CRYPTHASH);
      try
        CryptHashData(CRYPTHASH, @Password[1], Length(Password), 0);
        CryptDeriveKey(CRYPTPROV, CALG_3DES, CRYPTHASH, 0, CRYPTKEY);
      finally
        CryptDestroyHash(CRYPTHASH);
      end;

      StreamSource := TFileStream.Create(InFileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
      StreamDest   := TFileStream.Create(OutFileName, fmCreate);
      try
        GetMem(Buffer, BufferSize);
        try
            repeat
              BytesIn   := StreamSource.Read(Buffer^, BufferSize);
              Final     := (StreamSource.Position >= StreamSource.Size);
              if Encrypt then
                CryptEncrypt(CRYPTKEY, 0, Final, 0, Buffer, BytesIn, BytesIn)
              else
              CryptDecrypt(CRYPTKEY, 0, Final, 0, Buffer, BytesIn);
              StreamDest.Write(Buffer^, BytesIn);
            until Final;
        finally
         FreeMem(Buffer, BufferSize);
        end;

      finally
        StreamSource.Free;
        StreamDest.Free;
      end;
  finally
    CryptReleaseContext(CRYPTPROV, 0);
  end;
end;
```

and use in this way

to encrypt a file

```
 CryptFile('C:\temp\in.zip', 'C:\temp\out.zip','fdkjldf3832kka83' ,True);
```

to decrypt a file

```
 CryptFile('C:\temp\out.zip', 'C:\temp\in.zip','fdkjldf3832kka83' ,True);
```

2) about the location of the code to encryot and decrypt the data, will depends of the design of you application.

3) keep in mind that if your application crashes your data will be unprotected.

4) maybe the best option is build a small application which decrypt your data and launch your main application and stay monitoring the status until the main application ends. and then encypt your data again.

Comment: in case 4, if the computer power fails or any other "not clean" shutdown the data will be unprotected also.  If you don't take precautions, and the application is still running on a clean shutdown, the system may close the _monitoring_ application before the _working_ one, so it is possible to end with a unencrypted file anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try and get back to you!

Comment: jachguate, you are right, because that my primary recommendation was update to access 2007 or newer.

Comment: @jachguate:  "in case 4, if the computer power fails or any other "not clean" shutdown the data will be unprotected also. If you don't take precautions, and the application is still running on a clean shutdown, the system may close the monitoring application before the working one, so it is possible to end with a unencrypted file anyway." - THIS IS A BIG PROBLEM AND THEREFOR, I WILL ABANDON THE ATTEMPT AND talk the client into moving to a newer version of MS ACCESS or a diff database all together (MS SQL SERVER, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to check this site: http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/cryptography.html